# Tracking users in application

Tags: jsf-2

I need to track the users who are logged in to my application, and I'm trying to do this by using JSF2's applicationMap. So I create a list of users, and in my login bean I add (remove) users by doing this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put("usersList", usersList);
```

In the backing bean of the usersTracking.xhtml page I try to retrieve the list like this:

```
AppllicationMap map = (ApplicationMap)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap(); 
List users = (LinkedList)map.get("usersList");
```

But "users" always comes as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you perform the get operation directly after the put operation?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I made a silly mistake. Anyway I guess I'll just do this through the database because I don't think there's a solution with the applicationMap for the case I'm running several instances of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it an application scoped managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Users {

    private List<User> list;

    public Users() {
        list = new LinkedList<User>();
    }

    public List<User> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

This way you can inject and access it in every arbitrary managed bean by `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ArbitraryBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{users}")
    private Users users;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. But would it work across several instances of the application?

Comment: No. Your initial approach also not. I was just offering a simpler and more reliable way of your initial approach. To get it to work across multiple instances of the application, you'd need to store this information in a shared DB instead.

Comment: OK. Yes, I didn't think about it when I posted the question. I'm doing it through the db. But your suggestion would probably help when storing other kind of values, constants, etc. So thanks :)

Comment: You can always use an application scoped bean as a mediator between the DB and all other beans and views.